# Add days & dispaly output in string

Tags: php, date

I need to add days to given string date and display calculated date in string

This is what I have tried, but I could not make it work.

```
$date = date_create('1-Feb-2012');
$newDate = date_modify($date, '+2 day');
echo 'Your date is' . $newDate . '.';
```

This gives an error

> Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell the `DateTime` object how to format its output using [`DateTime::format`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php). So, for example:

```
$date = new DateTime('1-Feb-2012');
$date->modify('+2 day');
echo 'Your date is' . $newDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '.';
```

Also note that `modify` directly modifies the `DateTime` - it doesn't just return a new one, as [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) might lead you to believe - so I've removed the second variable. I've taken the liberty of changing the objects to the object-oriented form as well, which you should be using :)

[Here's a working demo.](http://codepad.org/Nt8PMznO)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DateTime::format`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) function.

usage:

```
echo 'Your date is' . $newdate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '.';
```

or

```
echo 'Your date is' . date_format($newdate, 'Y-m-d H:i:s') . '.';
```